# remove a field ("ID") from json file:

Tags: php, json

Trying to remove a field **and** value ("ID") from json file:
Can anyone please help with this?

JSON:

```
[{
  "Rating": "1600",
  "ID": "16733310",
  "Name": "LARRATEGUI,MARTIN",
  "Expires": "1000.10.10"
},{
  "Rating": "1353",
  "ID": "16429901",
  "Name": "ADDABBO,ERIC M",
  "Expires": "1000.10.10"
}]
```

TRIED THIS:

```
<?php 

$file = file_get_contents("uscf.json");
$file = str_replace('"ID": "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]",','',$file);
$array = json_decode($file, true);  

unset ($array.ID);
echo $array;
?>
```

---

Desired result

```
[{
  "Rating": "1600",
  "Name": "LARRATEGUI,MARTIN",
  "Expires": "1000.10.10"
},{
  "Rating": "1353",
  "Name": "ADDABBO,ERIC M",
  "Expires": "1000.10.10"
}]
```

Comment: You tagged `javascript`, but you `TRIED THIS` in PHP...? Which language?

Comment: What should the end result look like? You mention `"ID": "16733310"` in your question but your PHP code attempt looks like it wants to use a regular expression to remove all `ID` properties with 4 digit values

Comment: You are right. My mistake. Sorry. I'm a little tired.

Comment: The page has an error.

Comment: The desired result is that "ID": "16733310", and "ID": "16429901", should be gone. All 300 of them.

Comment: Right, so you want the same array or objects, just without **any** `ID` properties? Does it matter what the values are?

Comment: The ID is always 8 digits.

Comment: If you want to use a regular expression you have to use `preg_replace`, not `str_replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's practically always easier to deal with the data after it has been decoded, rather than trying to manipulate the JSON directly.

Decode the JSON from the file, remove the `ID` elements from all the arrays, then write the JSON of the updated array back to the file.

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("uscf.json"), true);
foreach ($array as &$el) {
    unset($el['ID']);
}
file_put_contents("uscf.json", json_encode($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of not mutating original data, I'd map the original array to a new one with the `ID` keys removed via [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-diff-key.php).

```php
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("uscf.json"), true);
$filter = ['ID' => true]; // only the key is important
$newArray = array_map(function($item) use ($filter) {
    return array_diff_key($item, $filter);
}, $array);
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/3nvtA